# Reduce partition size in AWS EC2 instances

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an EC2 instance on Amazon AWS but I need to create a new partition (/var/log), I never had the opportunity to perform this task so I’m a little afraid to do it.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           761M  784K  761M   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1   31G  2.9G   29G  10% /
tmpfs           3.8G  8.0K  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       34M   34M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
/dev/loop1       25M   25M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/4046
/dev/loop2      100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/10908
/dev/loop3      111M  111M     0 100% /snap/core/12603
/dev/loop4       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1997
/dev/loop5       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2284

NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0  33.3M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
loop1         7:1    0    25M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/4046
loop2         7:2    0  99.2M  1 loop /snap/core/10908
loop3         7:3    0 110.5M  1 loop /snap/core/12603
loop4         7:4    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1997
loop5         7:5    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2284
nvme0n1     259:1    0    32G  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1 259:2    0    32G  0 part /
```

I need to remove 20 GB from the partition (/) and assign it to a new one (/dev/sdb)

Any helps?
Regards,

Comment: StackOverflow is a Programming Q&A site. You might get a better response at: https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well, since it's AWS, and you know how to do it in other server, why not creating new EC2 instance and experiment on it. If not, try this:

1. Go to EC2 console, and go to Elastic Block Store > Volumes
2. Check your EBS Volumes
3. Go to Action modify volumes, and change the volume as you desire then save and wait until it's done.